# Macro con excel para sumar valores repetidos

Tags: excel, vba, macros

En una hoja "jennifer-cronograma-3" tengo los datos y La idea es que en la Hoja1 copie la fecha, país y mantenimiento. En la hoja1 debe sumar los valores Si la fecha y el país ya están.

Tabla de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto el código de la macro. En la hoja1 copia los valores que cumplen la condición, pero no he podido hacer que haga la suma de acuerdo a lo que se necesita.

```
Sub mM()
Dim fechaM As Date
Dim paisM As String

Dim ultimaFila As Long
Dim ultimaFilaHoja1 As Long
Dim contador As Long

Dim fecha1 As Date
Dim fechaToFind As Date

Dim result As Double

ultimaFila = Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

If ultimaFila < 4 Then
    Exit Sub
End If


For contador = 4 To ultimaFila
            
    If IsDate(Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 5)) = True And Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 4) <> "" Then
        'mtto
        fechaM = Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 5)
        paisM = Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 4)
        'm = Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 1)

        ultimaFilaHoja1 = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

            If IsNumeric(Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 1)) = True Then
                resultado = resultado + Sheets("jennifer-cronograma-3").Cells(contador, 1)
            
                
                
                Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(ultimaFilaHoja1 + 1, 1) = fechaM
                Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(ultimaFilaHoja1 + 1, 2) = paisM
                Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(ultimaFilaHoja1 + 1, 3) = resultado

                Else
                Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(ultimaFilaHoja1 + 1, 3) = 0
            End If
               
        End If
    Next contador
```

End Sub

Comment: ¿Por qué en VBA? ... Insertar > Tabla dinámica ... Filas: Fecha y País, Valores: Suma de mtto,,, Listo!

Comment: O si no, un countif o un SUMIF o un CONSOLIDATE, pero de todas las aproximaciones posibles, la que has elegido es la peor. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de tus datos de salida?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes es la primera imagen que puse, así debería salir. Tengo toda la información en una hoja aparte y en la Hoja1 sólo deben ir los datos que cumplen las funciones que ya establecí. Lo que necesito es que si ya están los datos en la Hoja1 que no los repita sino que los sume, por ejemplo: 14-08-2020 Colombia mtto 1 y 14-08-2020 Colombia mtto 1, lo que necesito es que quede 14-08-2020 Colombia mtto 2.

Comment: @Pollo ¿Esa solución sirve aún si los datos están en otra Hoja? porque la macro lo que hace es traer a Hoja1 los datos que cumplen la condición y apartir de ahí necesito lo que ya he comentado.

Comment: @Yeye727 claro, una tabla dinámica toma como fuente de datos cualquier rango o tabla que indiques... probalo primero, no?

Comment: @Pollo voy a probar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me expresé mal, quería decir que si podías poner cómo tienes los datos en origen, es decir, los iniciales. Mejor si se pueden copiar y pegar, no una imagen

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes la hoja de los datos es bastante grande, no sé cómo te puedo compartir eso por aquí.

Comment: Poniendo un ejemplo a mano, no tienen por qué ser datos reales ni completos, sino lo necesario para reproducir el problema y encontrar una solución.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes acabo de actualizar la info en la pregunta, una parte de los datos y el resultado esperado. La información está en otra hoja.

Comment: Vale, para hacer la suma, necesitas poder identificar las filas comunes. Un patrón que te podría servir sería concatenar país con las 3 fechas (sustituyendo antes las celdas vacias por una @, por ejemplo). Luego con un diccionario te llevas los valores únicos. Luego podrías hacer un SUMIF desde VBA y listo. Lo que veo más complejo de tu desarrollo es ordenarla como muestras, la manera en la que te salen las fechas al final, eso es lo que veo mucho más difícil automatizarlo porque no tiene una lógica.

También puedes resumir los datos en una tabla dinámica, pero no quedaría igual.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes vale, gracias!